# How do I build reusable JSP snippets in an app

Tags: templates, jsp, freemarker, taglib

I want to build reusable JSP components for an application that I am building. There are multiple ways to go around this. The ones that I know of include building JSPFragments and then stitching the page the together. But that is not an elegant way of doing it.

I am also trying to get mt head around JSP tag libraries to be able to build reusable components for JSP. I read in multiple places that tag libraries are falling out of favour fast. There are other frameworks like JSF and Freemarker templates by which I can build re-usable components. What do I use to build these components. Is there a preferred and contemporary approach I can follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this solve your problem. But anyway, I started to use FreeMarker, which is a really good template engine. It follows strict the MVC principal. These feature might help you to decide whether FreeMarker is good for your needs:

- [Including strategy](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_include.html). This is what I use to include header and footer template files in my view.
- [Macros](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_userDefined.html). Maybe you want but write your own directives. Unfortunately I have no experience with that.
- Using [jsp taglibs with FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html) is also possible.

Note that FreeMarker is just a template engine. You can not include java code into html like with jsp.

Answer (score 1):

If the component is simple you can use .tag files. They are easy to write. If it is more complex, use a tag library. It is a working solution used many times.